# Firebase Queue and Stripe Subscriptions

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I have read the other tutorials on how to integrate Stripe with Firebase, all of them require an external server. Recently I found [Firebase Queue](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-15-introducing-firebase-queue.html) and wondered if there would be any way to integrate `Firebase Queue` with a `Stripe Subscription` so that I wouldn't need to use an external `Server for Stripe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Queue is a library that you integrate into your existing node.js or web project. It does not replace the need for a server (to run nodejs) or web site (to execute the JavaScript).

Comment: Alright thanks, I reread the page and now I understand. *facepalm*

Comment: I'm also wanting to understand how to integrate stripe payments into a firebase app, did you find an optimal way to do this, if so can you suggest anything(guides or tutorials)?